# How to disable accordian panel tab in primefaces?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an accordion panel with 3 tabs Namely main, administration, system and i have 3 user roles student, staff and principal. I have no idea about how to disable administration tab while logging in as a student(Student role) through java code(Bean Class).Please tell me a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

as simple as that

```
<ui:param name="disableAdminTab" value="#{ not someBean.isUserAdmin }" />
<p:tab title="Admin" id="tab_admin" disabled="#{disableAdminTab}">
```

Suppose that SomeBean.isUserAdmin() is a function that returns if logged user has the admin role

Answer (score 0):

Did you try anything or have no idea how to do it? 
Maybe this can help you:

```
<p:tab title="administration" disabled="#{securityBean.isInStudentRole}">
```